# Making a redirect after a POST Request in Spring

Tags: javascript, spring, rest

I have a button with this onClick function in JavaScript which makes a post request to my Spring server with some data.(I'm not sending any data because I'm trying to solve this problem before that)

```
async function redirectToModel(model, make){
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/carmodel';

    const data = {
            make: getCodeName(make),
            model: getCodeName(model)
        };

    const params = {
            mode: "no-cors",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST"
        }
    await fetch(url, params);
}
```

My Spring controller looks like this

```
@Controller
public class NController {
    @GetMapping("/carmodelget")
    public String tester(Model model){
        System.out.println("get request");

        model.addAttribute("name", "test");
        return "carmodel";
    }

    @PostMapping("/carmodel")
    public String aaa(){
        System.out.println("post request");

        return "redirect:/carmodelget";
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is redirect the user from the page with the mentioned button to carmodel.html but I also want to send data to that carmodel.html, because it's a thymeleaf template.

The problem is that I get both "post request" and "get request" printed to the console in Spring, but the redirect never actually happens. What am I doing wrong?

Spring boot gives me an error: HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported

And the browser console gives me an error: net::ERR_ABORTED 405

Answer (score 0):

You can not redirect within a ajax call.

Try to send the redirect URL back as answer of the POST

```
@PostMapping("/carmodel")
public String aaa(){
    System.out.println("post request");

    return "/carmodelget";
    // or as json
    // return "{'url':'/carmodelget'}";
```

and then do a

```
window.location.href = newUrl
```

on the client side.

Comment: Hmh okay, but this is a problem because I want to use the make and model that I send in the post request for my thymeleaf template.. Also, this will make it so that some of my redirects are going to be from inside Spring and some are going to be from inside JavaScript, which will probably become a bit hard to track later on.. Is there any other solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Making a redirect with parameters is quite simple:

```
@Controller
public class NController {
    @GetMapping("/carmodelget")
    public String tester(Model model, String param){
        System.out.println("get request");

        model.addAttribute("name", param);
        return "carmodel";
    }

    @PostMapping("/carmodel")
    public String aaa(){
        System.out.println("post request");
        String param = "test";
        return "redirect:" + "/carmodelget?param=" + param;
    }
}
```

add some lines in springmvc web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>  
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>  
</filter-mapping>
```